# UberRides Carthage Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api, carthage

I want to use `UberRides` SDK in Objective-C Project. I checked pod for objective c but it is not available. So i tried `Carthage`.

Here is my `Cartfile`:

```
# UberRides
github "https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk" ~> 0.5
```

I use `carthage update --platform iOS` this command to installation and i am using xCode 8. But after some installation i am getting some error and i don't know how to handle so please help me.

Here is log of terminal:

```
*** Fetching rides-ios-sdk
*** Fetching ObjectMapper
*** Checking out ObjectMapper at "1.5.0"
*** Downloading rides-ios-sdk.framework binary at "v0.5.2"
*** Checking out rides-ios-sdk at "v0.5.2"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/mt/_rpb6s913b54yl1gfk0dt2qh0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.orgg88.log
*** Building scheme "ObjectMapper-iOS" in ObjectMapper.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "UberRides" in UberRides.xcodeproj
** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
A shell task (/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/jayesh/Desktop/CarthageDemo/Carthage/Checkouts/rides-ios-sdk/source/UberRides.xcodeproj -scheme UberRides -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES clean build) failed with exit code 65:
** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the latest 0.5 release is still using Swift 2.2

try updating your Cartfile to use the experimental Swift 2.3 branch

```
# UberRides
github "https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk" "swift-2.3-dev"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i am using xcode 8 for development and getting errors in it with old swift version.

Comment: Swift 2.2 is not supported in Xcode 8, you will need to use Swift 2.3. Alternatively, if you still have Xcode 7 installed (or download it from the Apple developer site), you can set which Xcode to use via the `xcode-select -s /path/to/xcode7.app/Contents/Developer` command